# Shipping charges

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping

I am using Magento 2. I want to prompt customers to add another item to their cart by providing them a discount on shipping for more than 2 items.

For ex : **shipping for 1 outfit is $15**, I want to display a message **"add another item to your cart for total shipping of $20"** These values must be taken from the excel sheet we upload in the panel and will vary from country to country and as per the weight of the final cart.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Any suggestions on extensions are also welcome.